# SelectList selectedValue not working

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, enums, extension-methods

I writed an extension method to read an enumerator value in a view and returns a Select's HTML to with all enumerators values and with the loaded in controller selected.

I Call it in view as:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemType, Model.ItemTypeList)
```

In my model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemTypeList { get; set; }
```

In my controller:

```
model.ItemTypeList = typeof(ItemTypeToSell).ToLocalizatedSelectList();
```

Also, my backend exension method is:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToLocalizatedSelectList(this Type enumType)
    {
        return (from object item in Enum.GetValues(enumType)
                let title = item.GetDescription()
                let value = ((int)item).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = value,
                    Text = title
                }).ToList();
    }
```

And it is an example of enumerator that I'm using:

```
public enum ItemTypeToSell
{
    [LocalizedDescription("Product", typeof(Expressions))]
    Product = 1,

    [LocalizedDescription("Addon", typeof(Expressions))]
    Addon = 2,

    [LocalizedDescription("Other", typeof(Expressions))]
    Other = 3
}
```

I'm returning all enum values in a list list and displaying they in a select with this code. I'm able to salve the selected value in the database. But the problem is it does not display the selected value when the page loads, aways shows the first, even when the method `ToLocalizatedSelectList` returns a selected item inside the ienumerable list.

I need to do something to it works after it or my error is about something else?

--------- **EDIT** -----------

How i solved the problem:

I changed the value from the enum itens in ToLocalizatedSelectList(this Type enumType), using the enumName as value. When I convert it to int, the code saves the value in the database, but the code does not consider it as a selected value.

The corrected method:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToLocalizatedSelectList(this Type enumType)
    {
        return (from object item in Enum.GetValues(enumType)
                let title = item.GetDescription()
                let value = item.ToString()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = value,
                    Text = title
                }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: You have a lot of odd and unnecessary code here. At the very least use `return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, ...);` And creating a second `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is just pointless extra overhead. But setting the `selected` property of `SelectListItem` (and repeating it again by setting the `selectedValue` value in the `SelectList` constructor) is pointless when you bind to a model property.

Comment: Internally, the `DropDownList()` and `DropDownListFor()` methods build a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and set the `selected` property based on the value of the property your binding to.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenMuecke. I changed the code and, with some tries, i found the error and I fixed it. Also, I edited the question case some person wants to see the solution if has the same problem. And sorry for my crap code, this kind of code is so advanced to me and i tryed to do something reusable.